# Android Studio project sync FAILED

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I attempted to import a project that Udacity's android course provided, but there were some issues. In the `build.grade(app module)` I changed `compile` to`implementation` and `testCompile` to `testImplementation`. The project synced successfully, but when I executed the project on the emulator it gave me the following errors.

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.1-5013011.
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
  - file:/C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
  - file:/C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar
Required by:
project :app
```

I think the required libraries needed to build cannot be found, but I don't know how to solve this. I googled the problem, but I can't find a solution.
My build.gradle file is this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    api 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

build.grade(project) is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: What is your **project** (not **module**) `build.gradle` look like? I am not sure if it is a question there.

Comment: Besides, the `aapt2` tools is located in `$ANDROID_STUDIO/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2`, why it is looking outside the Android Studio installation?

Comment: added build.gradle(project) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Beginning with Android Studio 3.2, the source for AAPT2 (Android Asset Packaging Tool 2) is Google's Maven repository.
>
>   To use AAPT2, make sure that you have a google() dependency in your build.gradle file.](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#aapt2_gmaven)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2).

> The AAPT2 (Android Asset Packaging Tool) is a build tool that Android Studio and Android Gradle Plugin.
>   Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0 and higher enable AAPT2 by default.

With [Android Studio 3.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#aapt2_gmaven) to use AAPT2, make sure that you have a `google()` dependency in your `build.gradle`:

```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          google() // here
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
      }
  } allprojects {
      repositories {
          google() // and here
          jcenter()
  }
```